# Enabling Satchmo Shipping Module Not from admin interface

Tags: django, satchmo, ups

I am using Satchmo in Django. I want to activate the UPS shipping module in it or make it the default shipping module in the using the settings file. But, I do not want to use the admin interface to do the same as described [here](http://www.satchmoproject.com/docs/dev/shipping.html#enabling-modules).

What can I do to achieve this or something similar like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shipping module settings in Satchmo are done in [django-livesettings](http://django-livesettings.readthedocs.org/en/latest/), i.e. they can be set through the admin interface (and are stored in the database). On production systems, however, this is often [disabled](http://www.satchmoproject.com/docs/dev/configuration.html#disabling-the-live-settings-system) by exporting the settings from the database and putting a corresponding LIVESETTINGS_OPTION into settings.py.

This means that you do not need to use the admin interface to change your settings. If you put them (and everything else you may have changed in the admin interface at YOURSITEADDRESS/admin/settings/) into LIVESETTINGS_OPTIONS, they will not be accessible through the admin any longer. There is a handy settings export function available at YOURSITEADDRESS/admin/settings/export/.